# As a undergraduate math student, what are some of the benefits of joining the American Mathematical Society?

Tags: mathematics, professional-association

I am a undergraduate student at a large university, and I was wondering what kinds of benefits are available as a member of the American Mathematical Society. I've heard that it is a great resource for networking, but other than that I have heard next to nothing about it.

Answer (score 1):

You get a discount on registration fee at their meetings, which is pretty much the biggest reason why people join AMS.

Comment: Considering I live very far from most of the meetings, I guess there isn't much of a incentive for me to join...

Comment: I have no real experience with the AMS, so I'm commenting instead of answering, but if there's an undergraduate chapter at your school, you might find it useful to go to their meetings just to meet people and see what your peers are doing. You might not even need to be a member to go to events. I know that the preceding is true for the ACM (the corresponding group for CS).